# Why are the radiatively generated neutrino masses finite?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, renormalization, neutrinos, beyond-the-standard-model

In the [Zee model](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0370269380903494) and the [Ma model](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0601225) of radiative neutrino masses, a naturally small neutrino mass is generated at the one-loop level. But loop diagrams are generally divergent. There is no mass at the tree-level in these models. Then how does the divergence go away, leaving a finite value?

A review of these models can be found [here](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/research/gr/workshops/PASCOS/2011/presentations/Schmidt-pascos2011.pdf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the relevant loop diagrams are not divergent.

In radiative neutrino models you are inducing the dimention-5 "Weinberg" operator,
$$\frac{(HL)^2 }{\Lambda}$$
through one or more loops. For renormalizable theories when a loop induces an an effective higher dimensional operator, the loop integral must be finite (since there are no counterterms to cancel away the divergence).

Diagrammatically we have things like,

[image]

In order to get the four external legs to the diagram, you must have several internal propagators which reduces the degree of divergence of the diagrams.

Comment: @SRS, all these neutrino models are renormalizable. That's the point. They are trying to build a renormalizable theory to replace the effective SM + dim-5 operator (non-renormalizable) model.

Comment: I get you.  But I'm asking like 't Hooft proved that the SM is renormalizable, is it also known that these models are renormalizable too? After all, they include new fields and renormalizability is not obvious. @JeffDror

Comment: Renormalizability is guaranteed for any Lorentz-invariant QFT which only includes dimension-4 operators or lower, satisfies gauge invariance, and includes only spin-0,1/2,1,3/2 fields.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I didn't know that.